# Show Animation while rendering large, local file

Tags: javascript, html, loading, large-files

I have a local HTML file which includes a large SVG node. If I open this file it renders the SVG file inside the browser which will take some time (due to filters). I cannot outsource the SVG node for example by loading it from file due to browser restrictions.
Is there a way, to overlay the full page with an animation which is visible from when I start the browser until the SVG content has been rendered?

What does not work is:

```
...
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #content {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="$('#content').css('display','block');$('#loading').css('display','none');">
  <div id="content">
  ...
    <svg> .... </svg>
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="loading">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

because the loading animation is not visible from loading the web page and is invisible before the SVG node has been loaded.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Sencha Labs seem to have an *afterrender* event for svg elements. I don't know too much about it but maybe it's a starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

The body `onload` event is triggered before the svg is loaded, that's why you don't see the animation when the page loads.
You need to add the #content <-> #loading toggle in the svg's `onload` event instead:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
  ...
    <svg onload="$('#content').css('display','block');$('#loading').css('display','none');"> .... </svg>
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="loading">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```